# CSS how to space between the elements and line-space vertically

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML. I'm trying to create a page that looks exactly like what I designed in XD, I created this using the language HTML & it is a Django project error page in HTML

The problem I'm having right now is that the margin and the placement of the elements are not matched and I found it difficult to align them accordingly. I need help and suggestion to make the spacing looks neater, text alignment, and the CSS thingy. The text font family wont override and what cause the issues.
[image: 1]
the Second pic shows the design I wanted to do actually.
[image: 2]
The code is implemented in Django/HTML.

```css
/* Error Page */
@import url('http://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/lemonmilk');
.body {
    color: #666;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", sans-serif;
    margin: auto;
}

.status-error-code {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 222px;  
    color: #5AC69D;
    font-family: 'Lemon/Milk', sans-serif;
}

.content-first-message{
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px; 
    font-weight: 400;
}

.content-middle-message{
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;  
    font-weight: 350;
}


.button-previouspage {
    font-family: "Segoe UI", sans-serif;
    align-items: center;
    appearance: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #0A79BD;
    border-radius: 200px;
    box-shadow: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #0A79BD;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-flex;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 0.25em;
    width: 10em;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.button-previouspage:active {
    border-color: #0A79BD;
    outline: 0;
}

.button-previouspage:focus {
    border-color: #05456C;
    outline: 0;
}

.button-previouspage:hover {
    border-color: #34CAE1;
}

.button-previouspage:focus:not(:active) {
    box-shadow: rgba(72, 95, 199, .25) 0 0 0 .125em;
}

.footer {
    margin-top: 5em;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    }
    
.footer .links {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 2em;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <!-- Character Encoding and Viewport Meta Tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Website Title -->
    <title> 404 error </title>

    <!-- Fonts & Backgrounds & CSS -->
    <link href="http://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/lemonmilk" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static 'landing/css/gotani.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static 'landing/css/errorpage.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
                
                
    <!-- Website Favicon/Icon  -->
    <link rel="icon" href="{% static 'landing/images/logo/favicon-96x96.png' %}">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="flex-item-middle-gotani-background">
      <a class="status-error-code"> 404 </a><br>
       <a class="content-middle-message">
          We're Sorry, <br> The page you're looking is not found! <br><br>
      </a>
      <button class="button-previouspage" type="button" onclick="history.back()"> < Go Back </button>
      
      <footer>
      <p>Here are a few links that may be helpful.</p>
        <p class="links">
          <a class="error-link-index"   href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a>
          <a class="error-link-aboutus"  href="{% url 'about_us' %}">About Us</a>
          <a class="error-link-contactus"  href="{% url 'contact_us' %}">Contact Us</a>
          <a class="error-link-signin"  href="{% url 'login' %}">Sign In</a>
        </p>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>
```

Comment: could you please shorten your question very much? if possible

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to center an element horizontally and vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461521/how-to-center-an-element-horizontally-and-vertically)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `body {text-align: center;}` ?

```css
/* Error Page */

@import url('http://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/lemonmilk');
.body {
  color: #666;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", sans-serif;
  margin: auto;
}

.status-error-code {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 222px;
  color: #5AC69D;
  font-family: 'Lemon/Milk', sans-serif;
}

.content-first-message {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.content-middle-message {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 350;
}

.footer {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.button-previouspage {
  font-family: "Segoe UI", sans-serif;
  align-items: center;
  appearance: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #0A79BD;
  border-radius: 200px;
  box-shadow: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #0A79BD;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-flex;
  font-size: 12px;
  height: 0.25em;
  width: 10em;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.button-previouspage:active {
  border-color: #0A79BD;
  outline: 0;
}

.button-previouspage:focus {
  border-color: #05456C;
  outline: 0;
}

.button-previouspage:hover {
  border-color: #34CAE1;
}

.button-previouspage:focus:not(:active) {
  box-shadow: rgba(72, 95, 199, .25) 0 0 0 .125em;
}

.footer {
  margin-top: 5em;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.footer .links {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 2em;
}

/* we add: */
body {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <!-- Character Encoding and Viewport Meta Tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Website Title -->
  <title> 404 error </title>

  <!-- Fonts & Backgrounds & CSS -->
  <link href="http://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/lemonmilk" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="{% static 'landing/css/gotani.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="{% static 'landing/css/errorpage.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">


  <!-- Website Favicon/Icon  -->
  <link rel="icon" href="{% static 'landing/images/logo/favicon-96x96.png' %}">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="flex-item-middle-gotani-background">
    <a class="status-error-code"> 404 </a><br>
    <a class="content-middle-message">
          We're Sorry, <br> The page you're looking is not found! <br><br>
      </a>
    <button class="button-previouspage" type="button" onclick="history.back()"> &lt; Go Back </button>

    <footer>
      <p>Here are a few links that may be helpful.</p>
      <p class="links">
        <a class="error-link-index" href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a>
        <a class="error-link-aboutus" href="{% url 'about_us' %}">About Us</a>
        <a class="error-link-contactus" href="{% url 'contact_us' %}">Contact Us</a>
        <a class="error-link-signin" href="{% url 'login' %}">Sign In</a>
      </p>
    </footer>
  </div>
  </div>


</body>
```